# REGEX to replace php4 style array $test[index] with $test["index"]

Tags: php, arrays, regex, eclipse

I need some help with replacing array indexes without double quotes.

I need to do this in eclipse and currently have the following REGEX to find the arrays, however, my replace is not replacing the value properly and it is truncating the text in the index which changes the index value.

Example:

```
echo "This is an example" . $testArray[testIndex];
```

The following regex highlights [testIndex] when i enter the REGEX in the find field in eclipse:

```
\[[^"$](.*?)[^"$]\]
```

However, when i use the following REGEX to replace the value found, it truncates the index.

```
\["$1"\]
```

Once replaced, the following happens.

```
echo "This is an example" . $testArray[testIndex];
```

becomes

```
echo "This is an example" . $testArray["estInde"];
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers,

Vish.

Comment: Put negated character classes into the capturing  group.

Comment: Alternatively, use lookarounds. `\[(?!["$])(.*?)(?<!["$])\]`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor Stribiżew, Tried Oliver's answer and it works and your answer also works perfectly with the excluded characters. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this regex:

```
\["?(.*?)"?\]
```

Online example here: https://regex101.com/r/bY9wL2/1